# Can I use subscriptions in my app using CloudKit when user is not logged into iCloud?

Tags: ios, cloudkit, cksubscription

Curious wether if user is not logged in can it prevent usage of subscription notifications?

Comment: Not sure what CloudKit has to do with this other than maybe the private database feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not create subscriptions (or create any records, or access a private database) unless there is a logged in iCloud account.